# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Que_2' to data type int

Tags: sql-server-2008

> > > > Select * from TCA Where questionid = 'Q_2'

New to SQL -- Getting a converting error but I'm not converting anything.

Comment: well, is `questionid` an `INT` or not?

Comment: Why would you be filtering on a non-integer? A non-integer will never be stored in an integer column.

Comment: It's labeled as INT but has other not int values in the column.

Comment: I think you are confused. Please post the table definition

Comment: @Lamak Probably. But When I do run the above code I do get the error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Que_2' to data type int"

Comment: Of course you are getting that message if the column is an `INT`

Comment: If the column is an INT, it takes an INT as an argument. You are providing a string.

Comment: Let me dig a little deeper, thanks.

Comment: Correct. this column was an int table. Cannot search for not int values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot filter an int value column with not int values, Such as the above question. For future reference refer to column properties for character type.